# What options are there for outputting to both a HDR TV and the VR headset on a v1 VR box?

Tags: playstation-vr

I have the first version of the playstation VR where the processing box does not support the HDMI standard (2.0) with HDR so it gets dropped and the Playstation is unable to detect that the TV supports HDR.

This means if I want HDR I have to unplug my cable from the processing box and put it directly into the back of my PS4.

Not only will this put extra wear on the ports but it is annoying to have to keep switching them around.

Are there any options out there that have been tested and will avoid me having to swap the cables round each time?

I am using the PS4 Pro.

Comment: I use a simple HDMI coupler (female to female) to replace my VR "processor" box when I use HDR. Another option I would try is using a splitter connected to the PS4, and a 2 port switch on the other end, or two 2-port switches on both sides, that still requires manual fiddling but no cable disconnection.

Comment: @JohnoBoy I brought a coupler and it is easy enough to switch between the two. If you put this as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a simple HDMI coupler (female to female) to replace my VR "processor" box when I use HDR. It's not optimal but it's quicker than disconnecting the two cables from the processor box and connecting one to both the TV and PS4.
[image: HDMI coupler]